# Difference in property binding for custom component in Ember V/s Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ember.js

In Angular, if we want to bind a property from outside for a custom component, we have to use "@Input" to kind of allow that property to be set from outside (i.e. from consuming component template)

Does EmberJS also have some sort of similar mechanism OR does it allow binding directly from the template (hbs) without adding/marking anything in the component JS? Is there any difference when it comes to Ember Octane V/s the earlier versions of Ember?

Answer (score 0):

yes it allows binding from outside the component without adding anything to the component js

in the  component hbs file

```
<p>{{@attribute}}</p>
```

from outside

```
<MyComponent @attribute="attributeValue"/>
```

also you can get the binded attribute from component js

```
@tracked mycomponentAttribute = this.args.attribute;
```

in the component hbs file

```
<p>{{this.mycomponentAttribute}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

no you don't necessarily have to add the input tag but you have to declare the property inside the component you are trying to pass the property to.

```
{{#each model as |post|}}
{{blog-post title=post.title body=post.body}}
{{/each}}
```

the blog-post component, define a property named title and this should work.

Comment: Thanks...but earlier solution seemed to suggest we dont need to explicitly define inside the component js...